# Firebase & AngularJS - Remove attribute don't work

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, firebase

I have an invitation app, and I want when member was accepted by current user, the array "waiting_guest" was deleted.

But the problem is when the current user accept (or refuse) member, the member stay in two array : "waiting_guest" and "confirmed_guest" (or "refused_guest").

This is a problem because in front view, the card for "accept or refuse" stay in same time of card "You have accepted member, contact him" (or nothing if current user refuse member)

How can I do for delete this "waiting_guest" when current user choose into "Accept" or "Refuse" ?

Html :

```
            <div class="card" style="height: 100%">
              <div style="border-bottom:none !important; background-image: url({{ guest.picture }});background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:50%; background-size:cover; text-align:center;position : absolute;height: 50%;-webkit-filter: blur(5px);width:100%;">
              </div>
              <h2 class="text stable" style="position:relative; font-size:36px !important"> {{ guest.name }} </h2>
              <img class="imgProfilEventGuest" ng-src="{{ guest.picture }}">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <span ng-click="acceptGuest(guest)" class="fa-stack fa-lg" style="font-size: 30px;">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:#6BFF72"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-check fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                  </span>
                  <br>
                  Accepter
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                  <span ng-click="refuseGuest(guest)" class="fa-stack fa-lg" style="font-size: 30px;">
                    <i class="fa fa-circle fa-stack-2x" style="color:#FF5252"></i>
                    <i class="fa fa-times fa-stack-1x fa-inverse"></i>
                  </span>
                  <br>
                  Refuser
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

JS :

```
$scope.acceptGuest = function(guest) {

  confirmedGuestRef.child(eventID).child(guest.user_id).set({
    user_id: guest.user_id,
    name: guest.name,
    picture: guest.picture,
    email: guest.email,
    phone: guest.phone
  })

  userRef.child(guest.user_id).child("confirmed_events").child(eventID).set({
    adressid: $scope.event.addressid,
    nameid: $scope.event.nameid,
    user: $scope.event.user,
    priceid: $scope.event.priceid,
    nbguestid: $scope.event.nbguestid,
    startdateid: $scope.event.startdateid,
    starthourid: $scope.event.starthourid
  })

  waitingGuests.child(eventID).child(guest.user_id).remove()
  userRef.child(guest.user_id).child("waiting_events").child(eventID).remove()
}

$scope.refuseGuest = function(guest) {

  refusedGuestRef.child(eventID).child(guest.user_id).set({
    user_id: guest.user_id,
    name: guest.name,
    picture: guest.picture,
    email: guest.email,
    phone: guest.phone
  })

  userRef.child(guest.user_id).child('refused_events').child(eventID).set({
    adressid: $scope.event.addressid,
    nameid: $scope.event.nameid,
    user: $scope.event.user,
    priceid: $scope.event.priceid,
    nbguestid: $scope.event.nbguestid,
    startdateid: $scope.event.startdateid,
    starthourid: $scope.event.starthourid
  })

  waitingGuests.child(eventID).child(guest.user_id).remove()
  userRef.child(guest.user_id).child("waiting_events").child(eventID).remove()
}
```

Please, save my day (I can add code if you want) !!

Thanks all for reading and asking !

Comment: I'm having a hard time figuring out exactly what you're looking for.  When your user either accepts or refuses a guest, you would like that user to be removed from another list called "waiting_events" ? Is the code you have included operational? Is the only issue that the user is not being removed from the waiting list?

Comment: This isn't functional code. Nothing is calling these methods. Is all this code necessary to demonstrate the (unspecified) error? What happens if you add callbacks to those set commands? How have you verified they are being run?

Comment: I've found solution, thanks for your intervention ! :)